# 英語版と日本語版でアカウントの設定やプロフィール、信用度は共有される？

Tags: サポート, アカウント

Stack Overflow の英語サイトと日本語サイトに同じGoogleアカウントでログインしていると、ユーザの基本設定やプロフィールは両サイトで共有されていると思えば良いのでしょうか？少し触った感じだと、少なくともプロフィールの説明は共有されているようですが、信用度は共有されていません。

個人的には、英語サイトでは英語のプロフィール、日本語サイトでは日本語のプロフィールを使うといった事が出来て欲しいと思います。

あと、日本語サイトだと本サイトとメタで信用度が異なるんですが、これはバグでしょうか？
英語サイトだと信用度は同じになっているので。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

わかるところだけ:

### 基本設定

- 他のサイトと共有される設定: 受信箱の通知設定、ニュースレターの設定、「フィルターされた質問」の設定
- 共有されない設定: それ以外

### プロフィール

プロフィールを保存する時に、日本語版サイトにのみ反映するかどうかを選べます。「保存」ボタンの下あたりに説明があります。

### 信用度

[ポルトガル語版](http://pt.stackoverflow.com)をみると、英語版とは信用度は共有しない、という運用のようです。日本語版の信用度も、英語版からは独立したものになると思います。

### メタでの信用度

これはバグかな?

Comment: プロフィールは日本語版サイトのみの反映が出来るんですね。情報ありがとうございます。